# Fixing designer problems

Tags: c#

After compute restart and open simple desktop project I found error `To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved:`

[image]

call stack:

```
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.NativeMethods.ThrowOnFailure(Int32 hr, Int32[] expectedHRFailure)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.DesignerDocDataService.GetFileDocData(String fileName, FileAccess access, String createTemplate, Boolean addToHostList, Boolean nestedItem)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomProvider.OnParseBegin(TextReader reader)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomParser.Parse(TextReader codeStream)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.MergedCodeDomParser.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeParser.Parse(TextReader stream)
at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.Parse(TextReader codeStream)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.CodeDomDocDataAdapter.get_CompileUnit()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost host)
```

How to fight with such errors and bring my form designer back?

Comment: Go to the Designer's cs file, copy and then delete everything in `InitialiseComponent`. The error should be gone. Now add the code for each component back in, one after another. And you check if the error appears again each time you add a component. Then you will know exactly which component is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You must have deleted something and You must delete it from designer. If you had done a delete operation , go to designer page and delete it from here also. Than if do you want add your control again, you can add it after this operation

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was observing this error, because some other developer has updated the design file and my Visual Studio and his Visual Studio were not of same versions.
What I did to make it work, opened the Designer's file, remove the lines that he updated and error was gone.
But unfortunately I had to make those UI changes again on my side.
So, if multiple people are working on same application they must have same Visual Stud